# Rails 3: respond_with errors on undefined URL helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Artwork` model that is manipulated only by API endpoints right now. (You'll see why this is important shortly). Those API endpoints are declared like so in my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1, :defaults => { :format => :json } do
    resources :artworks, :only => [:create, :destroy, :index, :show, :update]
```

This results in the following routes:

```
api_v1_artworks GET        /api/v1/artworks(.:format)                                             api/v1/artworks#index {:format=>:json}
                POST       /api/v1/artworks(.:format)                                             api/v1/artworks#create {:format=>:json}
api_v1_artwork  GET        /api/v1/artworks/:id(.:format)                                         api/v1/artworks#show {:format=>:json}
                PUT        /api/v1/artworks/:id(.:format)                                         api/v1/artworks#update {:format=>:json}
                DELETE     /api/v1/artworks/:id(.:format)                                         api/v1/artworks#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

Relevant code:

```
class Api::V1::ArtworksController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def create
    artwork = Artwork.create(artwork_params)

    respond_with artwork
  end
```

**The Problem**

When `#create` succeeds, `respond_with` chokes:

```
`undefined method `artwork_url' for #<Api::V1::ArtworksController:0x007fea1b4c67f8>`
```

It's expecting the helper for the HTTP Location to be `artwork_url`. How do I tell it to use `api_v1_artwork_url` instead? Can I alias the URL helper?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In this case, you'd need to specify the namespace for the responder. Try:

```
respond_with :api, :v1, artwork
```

Comment: just encounter this problem and I'm a bit confused on why we have to add the namespace.. can't find it on official documentation (or maybe I overlooked it)

Comment: You'll want to read about polymorphic routes: http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/polymorphic-routes/, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Comment: Does not work. just gets "undefined method `api_RESOURCE_url' for #"

Comment: Could you provide some context?